# Proving an accumulation point in a set of values of a sequence and the convergence point of a sequence are the same.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Here's what the problem reads: Suppose that the sequence ${a_n}$ converges to $A$, and $B$ is an accumulation point of the set $S=\{a_n|n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.  Prove that $A=B$.

This one seems deceptively easy.  However, I want to make sure that I don't miss the point, or find out I didn't notice something I should have.  If $|a_n-A|< e$, and $|a_n-B|< e$, does $A=B$ always?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your last question is no. The question is essentially the same as uniqueness of limit of a convergent sequence that can be proved by the triangle inequality:

$$
|A-B|\le |A-a_n|+|a_n-B|\to 0
$$

The RHS can be made as small as desired if $n$ is sufficiently large, so the LHS has to be zero, ie $A=B$.